# Magento: what did I break? "Fatal error: Call to a member function insert()" (version 1.4.1.1)

Tags: php, magento

I was trying to implement some new functionality, decided not to, tried to roll back, and now am stuck with this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Resource.php on line 96

The functionality I mentioned seems simple enough (remove a couple links from the customer account sidebar), and I believe I've removed the 3 files and the edit to local.xml, but just for full view on things, [here's exactly what i did](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/197799/#t260905).

Add'l info: I've got one custom module in place that I built for this site, and it was working prior to this glitch, but I'm wondering if something got screwed up in there maybe? (And I'm also thinking I might not have committed my last/working change, and now I'm in "doubt" territory about whether I screwed *that* up. It's a simple one though: 1 controller, 1 route.)

I've got no access to PHP error logs or the shell (`exec()` works great though), and the /var/system.log isn't adding anything more on my subsequent page-refreshes. And so this is where I'm stuck - Got any ideas on how to track this down? Thanks in advance!

Edit / here's the function that's throwing the error:

```
function setDbVersion($resName, $version)
{
    $dbModuleInfo = array(
        'code'    => $resName,
        'version' => $version,
    );

    if ($this->getDbVersion($resName)) {
        self::$_versions[$resName] = $version;
        $condition = $this->_write->quoteInto('code=?', $resName);
        return $this->_write->update($this->_resTable, $dbModuleInfo, $condition);
    }
    else {
        self::$_versions[$resName] = $version;
        // this is line 96:
        return $this->_write->insert($this->_resTable, $dbModuleInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code from `Resource.php` around line `96`? The error says you've got a call to an undefined object using method (`->insert()`). See: http://codepad.org/6QCm1UjL

Comment: just edited the post to include that, thx!

Comment: Seems like something is still wrong in your `local.xml`, magento as I understood from your words, magento can't initialize db write connection.

Comment: @Zyava, you were dead-on correct. This was a case of me being a total Mage::n00b, and it caught me out: my app/etc/local.xml connection node was missing the `<active>1</active>` node.... I must have unintentionally deleted it in the process of trying to roll back my changes. Slapping my forehead. Thanks very much!

Comment: @YellowShark please add your lastest comment as the answer to this post to help others because you were right, the `<active>0</active>` was causing the problem in my case too